# A problem in Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

If $f, g : S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ such that we have $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for every $x \in S^{n}$, then $f \sim a_{n} \circ g$.

(Where $a_{n} : S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ is defined by $a_{n}(x)=-x$)

I tried to solve this by Brouwer degree concept. But there was no result. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: To prove two maps are homotopic, the basic strategy, and often the best strategy, is to use your mathematical imagination to write down an appropriate formula for the homotopy, such as in the answer given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $h=a_n\circ g$. Then $f(x)\ne -h(x)$ for all $x$. So in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$
the line segment joining $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ **never** passes through the origin.
Then $\Phi_t(x)=(1-t)f(x)+th(x)$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $h$ within $\Bbb R^{n+1}-\{0\}$. We can scale that to a homotopy in $S^{n+1}$:
$$\Psi_t(x)=\frac1{\|\Phi_t(x)\|}\Phi_t(x).$$